With thunder client testing time, I am using jwt token, but I am getting error and unable to access authentication
When trying to check with thunder client with jwt token, I am getting error message
 "invalid token"

Whatever Token generate successfully, but with this token I can't authenticate & getting error
Here is the token generate code, it works fine
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const connectDB = require('./db/db');
const User = require('./models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/token', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        const token = jwt.sign(user._doc, 'secret-key', { expiresIn: '2h' })     

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Token generated successfully", token });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});

For reference, successfully generated token:
{
  "message": "Token generated successfully",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NjYzNDVkMDRjODMxZDA4YWQ5MzQ5NzEiLCJuYW1lIjoia2F0ZSIsImVtYWlsIjoia2F0ZUBrLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkFETUlOIl0sImFjY291bnRTdGF0dXMiOiJQRU5ESU5HIiwiX192IjowLCJpYXQiOjE3MTgwMzU3NTEsImV4cCI6MTcxODAzOTM1MX0.qkF_UxmQs34uYLeOi9rj3pS8y-FSLX0QNjLCzFz_7Ls"
}

Thunder Client Testing, here is the parameter what I am using
Here is the snippet details:
Headers- > Http headers
Accept: */*

agent: Thunder Client

Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

Product route code:
app.get('/product', async (req, res) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization
    console.log('token: ' + token)

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization access' });
    }

    try {
        token = token.split(' ')[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret-key');
        const user = await User.findById(decoded._id);
        console.log(user);

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization user access' });
        }

    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'I am a private route' });
})

Problem clearly visible here, the error message is:
Invalid token:
{
  "message": "Invalid Token"
}

Status: 400 Bad Request

Size: 27 Bytes

Time: 16 ms

My steps:

I took different token with different user, but error is the same with the thunder client

I upgrade the thunder client version but same result

New & different token unable to work



Does console.log('token: ' + token) print anything in  /product route ?

Token shows successfully

Then check error using console.error(e); within the catch() block.Only then you will understand for which reason you are getting error.Invalid token doesn't say anything about why this error occur. check the error and let me know.

Hmm, thanks for  bringing the answer into my notice. upvoting it.

Welcome, for your comments

1st step:
Open Thunder Client, and Hit Route:  /product
Auth-> Bearer-> Bearer Token: put token / in your case
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NjYzNDVkMDRjODMxZDA4YWQ5MzQ5NzEiLCJuYW1lIjoia2F0ZSIsImVtYWlsIjoia2F0ZUBrLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkFETUlOIl0sImFjY291bnRTdGF0dXMiOiJQRU5ESU5HIiwiX192IjowLCJpYXQiOjE3MTgwMzU3NTEsImV4cCI6MTcxODAzOTM1MX0.qkF_UxmQs34uYLeOi9rj3pS8y-FSLX0QNjLCzFz_7Ls
2nd step:
Then start your above mentioned steps
Hope it helps you
